# How to remove a div on component unmount using react?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I want to remove a div element on component unmount using react.

I create a div with id portal in usecallback method. I want to remove it on component unmount how can I do it.

below is my code,

```
function Dialog () {
    const [portal, setPortal] = React.useState<HTMLDivElement | null>(
        (document.getElementById('portal') as HTMLDivElement) || null
    );
    const createPortalIfNotExists = React.useCallback(() => {
        if (portal === null) {
            const el = document.createElement('div');
            el.id = 'portal';
            document.body.appendChild(el);
            setPortal(document.getElementById(
               'portal'
            ) as HTMLDivElement);
        }
    }, [portal]);

    createPortalIfNotExists();

    if (portal === null) {
        return null;
    }

    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <>
            <div>
                {children}
            </div>
       </>,
       portal
   );
```

}

I have two questions here, can useEffect be instead of usecallback in this case. and how to remove the div with id portal on component unmount.

Could someone help me with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By using the React.useEffect internal return method, you can do it. for example:

```js
function Dialog () {
    const [portal, setPortal] = React.useState<HTMLDivElement | null>(
        (document.getElementById('portal') as HTMLDivElement) || null
    );
    const createPortalIfNotExists = React.useCallback(() => {
        if (portal === null) {
            const el = document.createElement('div');
            el.id = 'portal';
            document.body.appendChild(el);
            setPortal(document.getElementById(
               'portal'
            ) as HTMLDivElement);
        }
    }, [portal]);

    React.useEffect(() => {
      createPortalIfNotExists();

      return () => {
         const portalElement = portal || document.getElementById('portal')
         portal.remove();
      }
    }, [])

    if (portal === null) {
        
        return null;
    }

    return ReactDOM.createPortal(
        <>
            <div>
                {children}
            </div>
       </>,
       portal
   );
``
```

Answer (score 0):

I am sorry to get late to the party, but actually, you don't need to perform any remove action if you manage the state properly.

### DON'T REMOVE MANUALLY THE CONTENT OF A PORTAL!!

By setting a boolean state of isModalOpen you can later in your code do something like the following. The portal just won't be created if the boolean is off. You won't need to remove manually any child.

```
   {isModalOpen && modalContent && createPortal(
     modalContent,
     portalRoot,
)}
```

Codewise that means that you could clean up your Dialog component into a useCreatePortal hook and a ModalContext:

### useCreatePortal

```
import {useEffect} from "react";
import _ from "lodash";

const useCreatePortal = (modalId = 'portal', tagName = 'div') => {
    const portalRoot = document.getElementById(modalId);
    const portalElement = document.createElement(tagName);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (_.isNull(portalRoot)) {
            portalElement.setAttribute('id', modalId);
            document.body.appendChild(portalElement);
        }

        return () => {
            if (!_.isNull(portalRoot)) {
                document.body.removeChild(portalRoot);
            }
        }
        // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    }, [modalId, tagName])

    return {modalId, portalRoot}
}

export default useCreatePortal
```

Now, imaging that this Modal is a thing that only one at the time is allowed, we could create a Context Provider that would expose a way to toggle the modal, and to specify which content to render:

### ModalProvider

```
const ModalProvider = ({children}) => {
    const {portalRoot} = useCreatePortal();
    const [isModalOpen, setIsModalOpen] = useState(false);
    const [modalContent, setModalContent] = useState(null);

    const openModal = (componentToRender) => {
        setIsModalOpen(true);
        setModalContent(componentToRender);
    }
    const closeModal = () => {
        setIsModalOpen(false);
    }

    return (
        <ModalContext.Provider value={{isModalOpen, openModal, closeModal}}>
            {children}
            {isModalOpen && modalContent && createPortal(
                modalContent,
                portalRoot,
            )}
        </ModalContext.Provider>
    );
}

export default ModalProvider
```

### Provide the Context to your app:

```
ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root')).render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ModalProvider>
      <App />
    </ModalProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
)
```

### Usage in a component:

```
const MyComponent = () => {
    const {isModalOpen, openModal, closeModal} = useContext(ModalContext)

    const componentToRenderInThePortal = <div>hello</div>

    return (
        <>
            <h2>
                MyComponent
            </h2>
            <button onClick={isModalOpen ? closeModal : () => openModal(componentToRenderInThePortal)}>
                {isModalOpen ? 'Close Modal' : 'Open Modal'}
            </button>
        </>);
};

export default MyComponent;
```

### TLDR

You don't need to clean up the dom element created by the portal manually. Use React's state to render it or not conditionally, as shown in the ModalProvider.